# swift 2.0 как работает анимация

Tags: swift

Если изображение уходит за пределы экрана, оно само выводится из системы (памяти) или для этого обязательно нужно использовать
`{ animationFinished in self.gor.removeFromSuperview() })`, чтобы удалить?

```
gor = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(300, 0, 150, 350))
gor.image = UIImage(named: "gor0002b.png")
self.view.addSubview(gor)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
    self.gor.frame = CGRect(x:-200, y: 750, width: 350, height: 530)
}, completion: nil})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объект находится в памяти пока у него есть хоть один владелец, другими словами, пока его retainCount > 0. В вашем случае, добавление объекта в массив subview какого то вью, увеличивает его retainCount на 1, и чтобы объект удалить из памяти (при условии, что у него нет других владельцев) его надо убрать из массива view.subviews посредством выполнения `-removeFromSuperview`.

Положение вью на экране никак на этот механизм не влияет.

Comment: когда делаю { animationFinished in self.gor.removeFromSuperview() }) - после одного цикла все и заканчивается ( анимация стартует по таймеру с повтором...) добавил options: .Repeat -         UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat], animations: {

            self.addView.frame = CGRect(x: -380, y: 525, width: 400, height: 80) }, completion: {animationFinished in self.addView.removeFromSuperview()  }) - тоже самое - один цикл и все...что-то такое идет не так....@Max Mikheyenko

Answer (score 0):

Объект будет жить пока жив родитель, в независимости от того, виден он или нет. Свифт не может знать понадобится он вам позже или нет.

Comment: а жаль...спасибо @iosp